# Changing scroll bar to the left of a div

Tags: html, css, wordpress, scroll, scrollbar

I'm bulding a Wordpress site that has a "box" for the main article. This is build using CSS and several Divs around the article. This all works fine, the only problem is that when I need a scroll bar, it apears outside of the right box border.

See for yourself (with awesome perfect red circle around it!).

[image: ScreenShot]

Basically, I want it to stay IN the article, so in the left side of the last image (the right side border). I read around the internet, and I found that you can reverse the scroll bar using dir="rtl", but that will reverse all the scroll bars, and thats not really what I want.

[EDIT - To make it clear, I don't want it in the left side of the article itself, just inside the box on the right side of the text. This is sort of what I want, but as you see, it messes up the article box. I want it sort of in that position, but without screwing up the article.]

[image: Screenshot 2]

[End edit]

This is the CSS (this comes from a modded template, so excuse me if there are obvious errors):

```
.article {
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.article-corps-title {
    background:url(images/article_sprite.png) no-repeat;
    background-position:0 -17px;
    min-height:70px;
    max-height:142px;
    position:relative;
}
.page-corps-title {
    display:block;
    /*background:url(images/article_sprite.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: 13px -65px;*/
    background:url(images/articlebox.png) no-repeat;
    background-position:15px 0px;
    height:80px;
}
.article-top {
    position:absolute;
    top:13px;
    right:25px;
}
.article-top a {
    display:block;
    font-size:10px;
    font-weight:700;
    color:#aaa;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:4px 12px 0 0;
    background:url(images/icons.png) no-repeat;
    background-position:top right;
}
.article-date {
    position:absolute;
    left:11px;
    top:26px;
    display:block;
    width:40px;
    text-align:center;
}
.article-date .month {
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:700;
    line-height:15px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.article-date .day {
    font-size:22px;
    font-weight:700;
    color:#FFF;
}
h2.page-title {
    text-align:center;
    font-size:26px;
    font-weight:700;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    color:#000000;
    text-shadow:#CCC 0 0 2px;
    max-width:565px;
}
h2.article-title {
    font-size:26px;
    font-weight:700;
    margin-left:80px;
    padding-top:30px;
    color:#ce0709;
    text-shadow:#CCC 0 0 2px;
    max-width:565px;
}
h2.article-title a, h2.page-title a {
    color:#ce0709;
    text-decoration:none;
}
h2.article-title a:hover,h2.page-title a:hover {
    color:#E00
}
.article-meta-autor {
    font-size:11px;
    color:#aaaaaa;
    margin-left:80px;
    background:url(images/icons.png) no-repeat;
    background-position:left -15px;
    padding:4px 0 4px 20px;
    max-height:11px;
    line-height:14px;
}
.article-meta-autor a, .article-meta-keywords a, .article-meta-comments a {
    color:#aaaaaa;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:700;
}
.article-meta-autor a:hover, .article-meta-keywords a:hover, .article-meta-comments a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}

.article-corps {
    position:relative;
    /*background:url(images/article_sprite.png) repeat-y;
    background-position:-683px 0px;*/
    background:url(images/articleboxmiddle.png) repeat-y;
    background-position:-5px 0px;
    /*min-height: 250px;*/
    height:300px;
    margin-left:20px;
    padding:13px 43px 0px 50px;
    line-height:20px;
    overflow:auto;/*hidden;*/
}
.article-read-more {
    margin:0px auto;
    width:164px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
}
.article-read-more a {
    display:block;
    width:156px;
    height:26px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:9px;
    background:url(images/read_more.png) no-repeat;
    background-position:top left;
    font-weight:700;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.article-read-more a:hover {
    background-position:bottom left;
}
.article-meta-keywords {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:50px;
    background:url(images/icons.png) no-repeat;
    background-position:0 -34px;
    padding-left:20px;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#aaa;
    max-height:20px;
    max-width:450px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.article-meta-comments {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:45px;
    background:url(images/icons.png) no-repeat;
    background-position:0 -54px;
    padding-left:20px;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#aaa;
}
.article-meta-keywords a {
    color:#aaa;
    font-weight:700;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.article-meta-keywords a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.article-footer {
    display:block;
    /*background:url(images/article_sprite.png) no-repeat;
    background-position:14px -15px;*/
    background:url(images/articlebox.png) no-repeat;
    background-position:15px -420px;
    height:45px;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You should check the Width and Padding around the viewable area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `dir="rtl"` to give direction to the text. The scrollbars will appear to the left.
Then use `dir="ltr"` to the inside elements such as `p, div` etc to nullify the effect. This way, `dir="rtl"`

Here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/dcLQQ/ 
I works in Firefox though, but in my chrome it doesn't.

**[Edit]**
Below is the fiddle to shift the scrollbar slightly to the left- 
http://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/fPGy8/1/

I don't think there is any other solution that you can fix apart from the above.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but thats not exactly what I want. I think my question was a bit confusing, so I edited it with another screenshot to hopefully explain a bit better. I dont actually want the scroll all the way to the left, just be a bit to the left, still to the right of the text.

Comment: Thanks a lot! After some fiddling (haha), I got it to work with your second solution. Just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

this is not a solution to your problem but just a suggestion:

be aware that you're going against the standard behaviour your users would expect - a scrollbar always appears on the right for left-to-right languages, and this could be bad usability. As you are not creating a site that requires RTL, it would be better to not change the standard browser behaviour.

Comment: I apreciate your concern, but I dont think i'm explaining myself correctly. I dont want a scroll bar on the left side, I just want it inside the box on the right side of the text. As it is, it apears outside of the box because its aligning to the right side of the image, and I want the image to go on, but the scroll to be in a fix position, like say, around ~520px after the article.

Comment: I see now what you mean, but without html / fiddle it's not simple to solve, if you could provide that we can help further

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given enough code (structure) for me to give a specific answer, but it looks as though you could just narrow the div that contains the article.

Comment: I believe I already tried that, but the problem is that it messes up the image (the entire right border). It might be me not knowing how to do it properly, but last time I tried applying that, it changed the "image" too. In theory, I want it to be over the image, and it always appears when it ends. Example https://dl.dropbox.com/u/19966409/screenshot2.jpg .